# Java client code for SOAP call with request header

Tags: java, soap

[--soap ui screenshot--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ikK.png)
Can anyone suggest me a sample java client code for this soap call. Find the soap ui call in the screenshot.
Facing problem while passing the header in java. The token and passcode must be present as a soap header while trying to communicate to the server.

Comment: This is easily available through google search. Did you try ?

Comment: You need a tool for sending? Jmeter postman or soapui